# Does gc.collect really release memory?

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection, free, collect

I am trying to release memory using gc.collect(). But I do not really understand how it works. For example:

[image]

Before I run del and gc, the used memory is 58g. After running them, the used memory is still 58. It looks that no memory has been released. I sense gc is different than shutting down python and starting again, which actually release memory.

So I am wondering how to actually release the memory so that I can load other data?

Comment: No, `gc.collect()` runs the *auxilliary garbage collector in CPython*, which only handles reference cycles. If there are no reference cycles, it won't do anything. Python uses automatic memory management, it exposes *no way to release memory*. CPython uses reference counting as its main memory management strategy. As soon as a reference count reaches zero, and object is reclaimed immediately.

Comment: Note, `del x` **does not free memory**. It *deletes a name from a namespace*. If that name *happens* to be the last reference to an object, then that object will be reclaimed. So you shouldn't expect `del x` to result in any released memory if the object is still referenced somewhere else

Comment: So, it looks like you are in an IPython REPL. Note, that saves the result of anything evaluated in a history! So anything you've evaluated that gets printed is still being referenced in that history. So fi you do `foo = some_complicated_stuff()` then `foo` to see the result, that is now referenced in `foo` and in the history of the IPython repl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your OS, it may not take back the released memory.

You can try out [malloc_trim](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) on Linux:

```
import ctypes

heavy_obj = create_heavy_obj()

# do some jobs

del heavy_obj
ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6").malloc_trim(0)
```