# How to properly clean the memory usage in Python code

Tags: python, pyspark, memory-management

I'm really curious about this behavior. I've the following python code that I'm running in a server and I'm monitoring the memory usage meter

```
# import some libraries
# Memory Usage: 310 MB
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("etl").getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc") 
            .option("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "Table1") \
            .option("user", us).option("password", pas).load()


df2 = spark.read.format("jdbc") 
            .option("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "Table2") \
            .option("user", us).option("password", pas).load()


df3 = spark.read.format("jdbc") 
            .option("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "Table3") \
            .option("user", us).option("password", pas).load()

input("First input")
# Memory Usage: 2 GB
spark.catalog.clearCache()
del df1
del df2
del df3
spark.stop
input("Second input")
# Memory Usage: 2 GB

sys.exit()
# Memory Usage: 310 MB
```

So, I'm loading a couple of datasets with pyspark and the memory increases. I put an input() just to freeze the script and watch the memory usage. After I delete all the variables, clean the cache and remove the spark session the memory is still giving me the same usage. Only when the script ends, the memory usage is decreasing back to his normal levels.

Thus my question is, how can you clean the memory usage from a python script in this kind of situations if removing the only variables that exist doesn't work?

I expect that the memory usage decreases

Comment: [>It is important to understand that the management of the Python heap is performed by the interpreter itself and that the user has no control over it](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html)

Comment: Force garbage collection? (`gc.collect()`)

Comment: @ScottHunter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491791/does-gc-collect-really-release-memory

Comment: One way to "control" the memory usage is to run the process in a subprocess. When the subprocess ends, it should return the memory back to the operating system.

Comment: I doubt that `spark.stop` actually does anything - surely that would need to be `spark.stop()`.