Memory reaches 1.2Gb just by running the __getitem__ method on each flow
I have a fastapi application that I use to store HTTP flows, for context I'm trying to build a tool that views HTTP fuzzing requests, it would store thousands of requests for further analysis (like searching for specific content, viewing the requests and responses, etc ) as the tool running on fuzzing data, 90% of the the time the server returns 404, 403 kind of pages which are for the most part exactly the same regardless of the requested path.
here is a test for how the program is supposed to run and how the memory leak arise:
 for i in $(seq 1 5000); do curl http://localhost:8023/nonexisting-path$1 --proxy http://localhost:8081 --insecure --location; done > /dev/null

the tool is running on port 8082 on localhost, the proxy is running on 8081, and another test server that is running on port 8023.

the proxy when it sends and receives the response it chunks the request-body and response body and hashes them and then sends it to the server using POST http://localhost:8082/store/ endpoint.

the server stores the flow in the code below using the store_flow function and the __setitem__ method.

when I want to get flows I use the __getitem__ method to rebuild the chunked flow.

when I run the above curl command to store 5000 on the server ( the 404 response for the nonexisting-path{i} endpoint is about 250Kb in size) the server uses at most 150Mb of memory, and the flows are rebuild as expected.

but when I try to get all the 5000 flows from the server using GET http://localhost:8082/getContent/ the memory reaches 1.2Gb just by running the __getitem__ method on each flow, returning all flows worsen the problem but it returns back to 1.2Gb when the function exits, when I try to get those flows again the memory stays at 1.2Gb but adding more flows would increase the memory proportionally when I request them.


now I don't understand what is wrong with my code but the only thing I understand is that if I created objects locally in a function those objects are supposed to be deleted when the function returns ??
I also tried manually garbage collecting after each call to __getitem__ and the memory is still the same.
here is a MVP code that contains the same problem:

import datetime
import base64
import operator 
import xxhash
import base64

from functools import reduce
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.requests import Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse



def reduce_list_to_int(int_list:list[int]):
  """ reduce a list of ints to a single integer """
  return reduce(operator.xor, int_list, 0)

class HTTPFlowStorage:
  """ efficiently stores HTTP flows that are mostly identical """
  
  def __init__(self):
    self._flows = dict()
    self._hashed_content = dict()
    self._hashed_headers = dict()
    self._content_hashes_hashes = dict()
    self._headers_hashes_hashes = dict()
  
  def __getitem__(self, ts:str):
    
    if not self._flows.get(ts):
      return None

    flow = dict(self._flows[ts])
    hashed_bodies = self._hashed_content
    
    collected_req = []
    collected_res = []
    
    # collect request and response bodies from their hashes
    req = flow['request-body']
    res = flow['response-body']

    for i in req:
      collected_req.append(hashed_bodies[i])
      
    for i in res: 
      collected_res.append(hashed_bodies[i])
    
    # collect body and encode as base64 to help transfer bytes
    flow['request-body'] = base64.b64encode(b''.join(collected_req)).decode('ascii')
    flow['response-body'] = base64.b64encode(b''.join(collected_res)).decode('ascii')

    # collect hashed headers
    new_headers = {}
    for h in flow['request-headers']:
      v = flow['request-headers'][h]
      new_headers[h] = self._hashed_headers[v]
      
    flow['request-headers'] = new_headers
    
    new_headers = {}
    for h in flow['response-headers']:
      v = flow['response-headers'][h]
      new_headers[h] = self._hashed_headers[v] 

    flow['response-headers'] = new_headers
    
    return flow

  
  def __setitem__(self, ts:str, flow:dict):
    
    def _add_new_content_hashes(hashes, content):
      """Stores newly found hashes and their content in the hashes object """
      
      not_matched_res = 0
      for h in content:
        hi = int(h)
        if not hashes.get(hi):
          hashes[hi] = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(content[h])
          not_matched_res += 1
          
    def _add_new_headers_hashes(hashes, hdrs):
      """Stores newly found headers in the hashes object and returns
      the new headers """
      
      new_headers = dict()
      for hdr in hdrs:
        hv = hdrs[hdr]
        hs = int(xxhash.xxh3_64_digest(hv.encode('utf-8')).hex(), 16)
        if hs not in hashes:
          hashes[hs] = hv
          
        new_headers[hdr] = hs

      return new_headers
          
    # include new hashes in the hashed_content
    req = flow['request-body']
    res = flow['response-body']

    _add_new_content_hashes(self._hashed_content, req)
    _add_new_content_hashes(self._hashed_content, res)
    
    flow['request-body'] = list(int(i) for i in req.keys())
    flow['response-body'] = list(int(i) for i in res.keys())

    # hash and store headers
    req_headers = flow['request-headers']
    res_headers = flow['response-headers'] 

    nrh = _add_new_headers_hashes(self._hashed_headers, req_headers)
    nrsh =_add_new_headers_hashes(self._hashed_headers, res_headers)

    flow['request-headers'] = nrh
    flow['response-headers'] = nrsh

    # further hash the bodies content and check if there is a
    # body extactly like it in previous bodies and use it instead of
    # new body
    hb_res = reduce_list_to_int(flow['response-body'])
    hb_req = reduce_list_to_int(flow['request-body'])

    if hb_res in self._content_hashes_hashes:
      flow['response-body'] = self._content_hashes_hashes[hb_res]
    else :
      self._content_hashes_hashes[hb_res] = flow['response-body']

    if hb_req in self._headers_hashes_hashes:
      flow['request-body'] = self._headers_hashes_hashes[hb_req]
    else :
      self._headers_hashes_hashes[hb_req] = flow['request-body']
    
    self._flows[ts] = flow

  def values(self):
    return list( self[i] for i in self._flows)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self._flows)

  
CACHE = HTTPFlowStorage()
app = FastAPI() 

@app.post("/store/")
async def store_flow(flow:dict):
  """Stores a flow from the proxy in the `CACHE` object."""
    
  timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
  flow['timestamp'] = timestamp
  flow['index'] = len(CACHE) +1
  
  CACHE[str(timestamp)] = flow


@app.get("/getContent/")
async def get_history(req:Request):
  
  flows = CACHE.values()
  # returning None here would create the same problem.


  # not to return the all flows increases the memory leak even more ??
  return JSONResponse(flows[0]) 

running version:
python-version: python3.10.12
fastapi-version: fastapi==0.111.0
uvicorn-version: 0.29.0

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77604189/1204143

Your cache sounds like it is caching Request things. It is possible that you are accidentally putting something into the cache that has a reference to a web request, so the GC can't collect anything because every object created in a request has a referendce to it. So memory only goes up. I can't prove my suspicion. It seem unlikely this has anything to do with native code libraries not releasing memory.
